# I'm trying to add firebase in my dependencies and I get this

Tags: android, flutter

The plugins `firebase_auth, firebase_core` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise,
consider removing them since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:
https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

Comment: have you tried upgrade the version?

Answer (score 6):

Use **flutter pub outdated** to check if you have outdated packages and you can see them.

Then run **flutter pub upgrade --major-versions** to fix all your upgrade problems.

Check if you have all the updates.**flutter pub outdated**

Answer (score 4):

Run Flutter pub outdated

Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Answer (score 0):

Try to showing outdated packages with:

```
flutter pub outdated
```

After checked and make sure, then you need to upgrade some outdated package with this command line in your terminal:

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

its should fix your problem, and try correcting dependencies.